# Attributes not showing to choose in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

At my product page, when I go to Product Data, select “Variable product” and then click on “Variations” I get the message, “Before adding variations, add and save some attributes on the Attributes tab.”
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g22fL.png)

So… I went to the Attributes tab, created an attribute titled ‘Colors’, and ‘Size’.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbEcF.png)

With those saved, I went back to my saved product, went back to “Product Data”, selected “Variable product” and clicked on, “Variations”

But there I again see that message "Before adding variations, add and save some attributes on the Attributes tab.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've added your global attributes (**Products › Attributes**), you still need to select those attributes from the **Attributes** tab on the product edit page. You'll then be able to set up variations for a product.

1. Go to: **Products** › **Add Product** (or edit an existing one).
2. Select the **Attributes** tab in the Product Data. Use the dropdown menu to choose any of the global attributes that you’ve created.
3. Select **Add** to make the attribute type available for variations
4. Select the terms that you want to use for this product's variations (I've selected **Black** and **White** in the screenshot below).
5. Check **Use for variations**
6. Click **Save attributes**
7. You can now set up variations within the **Variations** tab

[image: Product page attributes tab]

Comment: This is what i need. Thank you so much